# How to keep linux-cloud-tools-virtual in sync with my kernel?

Tags: package-management, kernel, hyper-v

The Ubuntu 14.04 package [linux-cloud-tools-virtual](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-cloud-tools-virtual), used for compatibility with Hyper-V, depends on [linux-cloud-tools-3.13.0-44-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-cloud-tools-3.13.0-44-generic).  However, the standard installed kernel is 3.13.0-32, which requires installation of [linux-cloud-tools-3.13.0-32-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-cloud-tools-3.13.0-32-generic) instead.

Is this a bug?  Is there some way to get the appropriate version with the package manager and automatically keep it in sync even as the kernel gets upgraded over time?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) do the opposite thing — install `linux-image-generic` (or sth. like that) to ensure that also the kernel is updated, like the `cloud-tools`; they'll be kept in sync by Ubuntu people. This will also allow you to get security updates — which you do want anyway in almost any case.

You also probably want to setup automatic package updates through `unattended-upgrades`.

The only thing left to you is to reboot the machine when the kernel is updated, unless you let `unattended-upgrades` do that for you.

Comment: It seems that linux-cloud-tools-virtual and linux-image-generic are currently in sync at kernel version 3.13.0-63. But they were not in sync when I asked the question, and the former says in its description: "This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel cloud tools." which doesn't sound like a commitment to keep them in sync.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you had installed `linux-image-generic`, and assumed the packages would be in sync. I'm guessing then the answer is `This is a bug`, because I don't think there's another way to keep packages like these in sync. But I'm not expert enough to answer, and the only info I found is this other question: http://serverfault.com/q/670049/29689. If I were you, at this point, I'd ask upstream.

Comment: I think I probably have it just because it's the default. With them currently in sync, though, maybe it's not a problem any more. Thanks!